# Anything wrong with declaring variables like this?

Tags: android, database, string, declare

So there are sort of 2 questions here.

In my database I need 18 fields because in golf there are 18 holes (so 18 to store hits for each hole.)  Second I need to store the yardage for each hole (so thats 18 more.)

My question is, right now I am declaring them all as follows:

```
public static final String KEY_H1 = "h1";
public static final String KEY_H1Y = "h1y";
public static final String KEY_H2 = "h2";
public static final String KEY_H2Y = "h2y";
public static final String KEY_H3 = "h3";
public static final String KEY_H3Y = "h3y";
```

etc.

h1 being hole 1
h1y being hole 1 yardage

Is there a better way to do this?  Additionally, in the on create I will have to call h1 h1y h2 h2y h3 h3y etc.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 1. Will this tax the system a lot in terms of, cause the application to bomb out or run slower?
2. In the future, will this make it a pain to update the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could instead of having a "golf game score" table, have a "hole score" table. This table could then contain an int column for the hole, another column for yardage, and another game_id column.

Comment: I suspect Rob would regret it eventually if he *didn't* go this route.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will try this route, as it does make more sense.  Do you have any suggestions as to how I could differentiate 1 set of 18 holes from another?  Instead of course name, using the date or something?

Comment: It really depends on what you want to keep track of. The game_id column should be sufficient to distinguish one set of 18 holes from another, but you can also put in more data. If the date is important to you, then by all means store the date. If knowing which particular course this game was on is important, perhaps add a course table with data on the courses and add a course_id column to the game table. It all depends on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @Rob: Create a separate table that records each round as a whole. This doesn't actually need to have anything more than an _id column; that gives you a unique id for each game. You would then create a foreign key in the 'holes_played' table that references the _id column in the 'rounds' table. (You can certainly add additional info to the 'rounds' table, such as the date/time, course name, etc.)

Comment: One other suggestion: Try to keep static data -- such as the names of each course played, the players' names, the par of each hole on each course, etc. -- in separate tables from more 'dynamic' data, such as the score on each hole. Each of these items should probably be rows in their own tables, each with their own unique _ids. It may seem like this adds complexity, but it will pay for itself in simplicity over (not very much) time.

Comment: Dan, could I talk to you in chat for a few?  I have a few minor questions but dont want to clutter up this section.

Comment: @Rob: I don't see an option for a private chat, and I don't know which room to wander into (the Android room requires registration), and I *only* have a few minutes ATM. At the risk of being circuitous, you can try emailing me through the contact page at my blog (http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/contact/ )

Answer (score 1):

Tacking onto [Kabuku's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379542/anything-wrong-with-declaring-variables-like-this/6379591#6379591) answer: Suppose for a given round of golf, you want to find out how many birdies, eagles, bogies, etc. the player had; or you want to find out which holes had the best score against par, which had the worst, etc. Do you really want to write the same code 18 times, once for each hole; or do you want to be able to write the code once, as a loop or query over the holes, to find the result?

This is just one reason why you really, really want to make the hole number a parameter, instead of creating separate static variables or columns for each hole.

To answer the other part of your question -- would it slow down the system to declare a lot of public static final variables -- the answer is no. But in this particular case, it would eventually slow *you* down.

Comment: do you think it matters whether my primary key is _id or not?  trying to think of a reason that would stop me from making that key

Comment: @Rob: SQLite and Android's APIs really like it when you use _id as the name of the primary key column. I see no reason to argue with them :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would just store it as a string, since you have fields for something from *x* to *y*, which should always be in some sort of array form. The easiest way, I think, is storing it as:

`hits:yardage hits:yardage hits:yardage`*`etc...`*

In your database, then splitting the string by `:` and .

(And in response to your edit, yes, your current way will probably make it unnecessarily difficult to update the database structure.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd have two tables, a game table, and a hole score table.

The game table would have the date and course.

The hole score table would have the hole number, the yardage, the score and the _id of the record for the game in the game table.